# Which is better for exception handling?

Tags: java, exception

We have 5 possible exceptions and we want to handle them. Should i use 5 different catch or 
like that:

```
try {
  //...
}
catch(Exception e) {
 if(e instanceof IOException) 
 else if(e instanceof IllegalStateException)
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Note : you can use the following syntax if you want to apply the same operation for different exceptions : `catch (RuntimeException | IllegalAccessException e)`

Comment: Note 2 : an `instance of` is a proof of design flaw. There are few cases where this keyword is strictly necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using 5 different `catch` blocks is certainly better than emulating the same thing with `instanceof` operator. Just keep the ordering correct (most specific exception first, then the general one at the end):

```
try {

} catch (IOException exc) { 
    // do something
} catch (IllegalStateException exc) {
    // do something else
} catch (Exception exc) {
    // do something else for all remaining exceptions.
}
```

Also, if you have similar handling for some of the exceptions, and you're already on Java 7, you can take the benefit of multi-catch blocks:

```
try {

} catch (IOException | IllegalStateException exc) { 
    // do something
}
```

Comment: In addition to this, in JDK7+ you can 'group' exception handling by using `catch (IOException | IllegalStateException ex)` if you want to execute the same actions for different exceptions.

Comment: I don't doubt that you're right, but could you explain _why_ it's better to have multiple catch blocks than to use the _instanceof_ operator?

Comment: @AndrewMartin `instanceof` is rarely a good thing. Here using different `catch` statement allows the compiler to detect uncaught exceptions (except if you catch all exceptions with `catch (Exception e)`).

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks

Comment: If you use multi-catch block, do remember the exceptions that you are handling are related(parent-child).

Answer (score 2):

If you catch `Exception` and then have a cascade of `if-else if`s, you run the risk of *swallowing* any exception which doesn't match. The compiler will not enforce a concluding `else throw e` clause.

Furthermore, once you catch it as an `Exception`, you can't even throw it again if your method doesn't declare `throws Exception`, which it shouldn't.

To conclude, keep to the standard idioms unless:

1. they *prevent* you from doing what you need;
2. you have a very dedicated and trustworthy team of developers or at least additional checking tools.

Answer (score 1):

If the things, which are done for two or more exceptions are similar, combine them. But if you do so, do it right:

```
try {
    // foo
} catch (ExceptionClass1 | ExceptionClass2 | ExceptionClass3 e) {
    // error foo
}
```

For further information on multiple exception handling see: [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just go for multiple catch rather than using instance of

Java supports multiple catch statements for a reason, as of Java 7 you can even use a 'multicatch' like this:

```
try {
    ...
}
catch (IOException | OtherException | MyException e) {
    ...
}
```

More information :-

http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2010/05/better-exception-handling-in-java-7-multicatch-and-final-rethrow.html

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/catching-multiple-exceptions.html

Answer (score 0):

You should definitively use a `catch{}` block instead of emulating exception handling mechanics manually.

Newer versions of Java allows you to merge multiple exceptions in one single `catch{}` block:

```
try {
  // ...
} catch (E1 | E2 | E3 e) {
  // handle e
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best use more catch blocks with different exception variables.

Exactly like the example in your question.